# C++ Intel TBB and Microsoft PPL, how to use next_permutation in a parallel loop?

Tags: c++, algorithm, visual-c++, parallel-processing, permutation

I have Visual Studio 2012 with Intel parallel studio 2013 installed, so I have Intel TBB.

Say I have the following piece of code:

```
const int cardsCount = 12; // will be READ by all threads
// the required number of cards of each colour to complete its set:
// NOTE that the required number of cards of each colour is not the same as the total number of cards of this colour available
int required[] = {2,3,4}; // will be READ by all threads
Card cards[cardsCount]; // will be READ by all threads
int cardsIndices[cardsCount];// this will be permuted, permutations need to be split among threads !

// set "cards" to 4 cards of each colour (3 colours total = 12 cards)
// set cardsIndices to {0,1,2,3...,11}

 // this variable will be written to by all threads, maybe have one for each thread and combine them later?? or can I use concurrent_vector<int> instead !?
int logColours[] = {0,0,0};

int permutationsCount = fact(cardsCount);

for (int pNum=0; pNum<permutationsCount; pNum++) // I want to make this loop parallel !!
{
    int countColours[3] = {0,0,0}; // local loop variable, no problem with multithreading
    for (int i=0; i<cardsCount; i++)
    {
        Card c = cards[cardsIndices[i]]; // accessed "cards"

        countColours[c.Colour]++; // local loop variable, np.
            // we got the required number of cards of this colour to complete it
        if (countColours[c.Colour] == required[c.Colour]) // read global variable "required" !
        {
                    // log that we completed this colour and go to next permutation
            logColours[c.Colour] ++; // should I use a concurrent_vector<int> for this shared variable?
            break;
        }
    }
    std::next_permutation(cardsIndices, cardsIndices+cardsCount); // !! this is my main issue
}
```

What I'm calculating is how many times we will complete a colour if we pick randomly from available cards, and that's done exhaustively by going through each permutation possible and picking sequentially, when a colour is "complete" we break and go to the next permutation. Note that we have 4 cards of each colour but the required number of cards to complete each colour is {2,3,4} for Red, Green, Blue. 2 red cards are enough to complete red and we have 4 available, hence red is more likely to be completed than blue which requires all 4 cards to be picked.

I want to make this for-loop parallel, but my main problem is how to deal with "cards" permutations? you have ~0.5 billion permutation here (12!), if I have 4 threads how can I split this into 4 different quarters and let every thread go through each of them?

What if I don't know the number of cores the machine has and I want the program to automatically choose the right number of concurrent threads? surely there must be a way to do that using Intel or Microsoft tools?

This is my Card struct just in case:

```
struct Card
{
public:
    int Colour;
    int Symbol;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let `N = cardsNumber`, `M = required[0] * required[1] * ... * required[maxColor]`.
Then, actually, your problem could be easily solved in O(N * M) time. In your very case, that is `12 * 2 * 3 * 4 = 288` operations. :)

One of possible ways to do this is to use a recurrence relation. 
Consider a function `logColours f(n, required)`. Let `n` be the current number of already considered cards; `required` is a vector from your example. Function returns the answer in a vector `logColours`.
You are interested in `f(12, {2,3,4})`. Brief recurrent calculation inside a function `f` could be written like this:

```
std::vector<int> f(int n, std::vector<int> require) {
    if (cache[n].count(require)) {
        // we have already calculated function with same arguments, do not recalculate it again
        return cache[n][require];
    }

    std::vector<int> logColours(maxColor, 0); // maxColor = 3 in your example

    for (int putColor=0; putColor<maxColor; ++putColor) {
         if (/* there is still at least one card with color 'putColor'*/) {
              // put a card of color 'putColor' on place 'n'
              if (require[putColor] == 1) {
                  // means we've reached needed amount of cards of color 'putColor'
                  ++logColours[putColor];
              } else {
                  --require[putColor];
                  std::vector<int> logColoursRec = f(n+1, require);
                  ++require[putColor];
                  // merge child array into your own.
                  for (int i=0; i<maxColor; ++i)
                      logColours[i] += logColoursRec[i];
              }
          }
     }

     // store logColours in a cache corresponding to this function arguments
     cache[n][required] = std::move(logColours);
     return cache[n][required];
 }
```

Cache could be implemented as an `std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>>>`.

Once you understand the main idea, you'll be able to implement it in even more efficient code.

Comment: hmm.. I don't understand the idea, but I can see that you don't care about the cards that I have. How can this work if you don't know the cards? in my example I have 4 cards of each colour, and 3 colours total, so 12 cards. I edited my question to indicate that..

Comment: I do care. There is an `if` inside an `f` function, which checks for the number of cards of needed color left. I thought you'd be able to fill that code yourself.

Comment: mate, that's great I don't know how to thank you. It's better than what I was trying to do (parallel). I will need some time to understand it though. Thanks a lot for you time :)

Comment: what do you mean? I upvoted the other answer by mistake and I can't take my vote back now. I didn't want to upvote any answer, because I still don't know how to make my code run in parallel. I will try your other answer that explains how to make it parallel

Answer (score 1):

You can easy make your code run in parallel with `1,2, ..., or cardsCount` threads by fixing the first element of permutation and calling `std::next_permutation` on other elements independently in each threads.
Consider the following code:

```
// declarations

// #pragma omp parallel may be here
{ // start of a parallel section
     const int start = (cardsCount * threadIndex) / threadNumber;
     const int end = (cardsCount * (threadIndex + 1)) / threadNumber;

     int cardsIndices[cardsCount]; // a local array for each thread

     for (const int firstElement = start; firstElement < end; ++firstElement) {
         cardsIndices[0] = firstElement;
         // fill other cardsIndices with elements [0-cardsCount], but skipping firstElement
         do {
             // your calculations go here
         } while (std::next_permutation(cardsIndices + 1, cardsIndices + cardsCount)); // note the +1 here
     }
 }
```

- If you wish to use OpenMP as a parallelization tool, you only have to
  add `#pragma omp parallel` just before the parallel section. And use
  `omp_get_thread_num()` function to get a thread index.
- You also do not have to use a concurrent_vector here, this would
  probably make your program extremely slow, use a thread-specific
  accumulation array:

  ```
   logColours[threadNumber][3] = {};
   ++logColours[threadIndex][c.Colour];
  ```
- If `Card` is a rather heavy class, I would suggest using `const Card& c = ...` instead of copying each time `Card c = ...`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is an amateur friendly version of what @Ixanezis means

If red wins

the final outcome will be: 2 red, 0-2 green, 0-3 blue

Say the winning red is A, and the other red is B, there are 12 ways to get A and B.

The following are the possible cases:

```
Cases:            #Cards after A   #Cards before A #pick green #pick blue
0 green, 0 blue:    10! = 3628800     1! = 1          1          1
0 green, 1 blue:    9 ! = 362880      2! = 2          1          4
0 green, 2 blue:    8 ! = 40320       3! = 6          1          6
0 green, 3 blue:    7 ! = 5040        4! = 24         1          4
1 green, 0 blue:    9 ! = 362880      2! = 2          4          1
1 green, 1 blue:    8 ! = 40320       3! = 6          4          4
1 green, 2 blue:    7 ! = 5040        4! = 24         4          6
1 green, 3 blue:    6 ! = 720         5! = 120        4          4
2 green, 0 blue:    8 ! = 40320       3! = 6          6          1
2 green, 1 blue:    7 ! = 5040        4! = 24         6          4
2 green, 2 blue:    6 ! = 720         5! = 120        6          6
2 green, 3 blue:    5 ! = 120         6! = 720        6          4
```

Lets `sumproduct` those 4 arrays: = 29064960, then multiply by 12 = 348779520

Similarly you can calc for green wins for blue wins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::thread::hardware_ concurrency()` from `<thread>`. Quoting from "C++ Concurrency in action" by A.Williams -

> One feature of the C++ Standard Library that helps here is
>   `std::thread::hardware_ concurrency()`. This function returns an
>   indication of the number of threads that can truly run concurrently
>   for a given execution of a program. On a multicore system it might be
>   the number of CPU cores, for example.